# Get root parent site of current site

Tags: site-collection, site

Is there a way to get the root parent site, no matter how many levels deep you are in sub-sites? For example, in this structure:

```
- MySiteCollection
  - MyRootSite
    - MySubSite
      - MySubSiteOfSubsite
        -AnotherSubSite
```

So in the above example, I need to get the title property of the `MyRootSite` web site (not the `MySiteCollection` title) no matter which sub-site I'm in. I'm thinking server-side code needs to traverse the parent(s) and get the web site one before IsRootWeb becomes true. Is this correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SPSite.RootWeb` is the object you're after, in server side code ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.rootweb.aspx).

`SP.Site.get_rootWeb()` in client object model code ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee552834.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, James. I'm using this code but it's getting the site collection root, not `MyRootSite` from above example: `using (SPWeb oWebsiteRoot = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb) { Response.Write("root: " + oWebsiteRoot.Title); }`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're confusing the definition of Site Collection and Web sites. Site Collections strictly don't contain content, only Web Sites. A Site collection has only one Root Web Site, at the top level, which is found by SPSite.RootWeb, and it's impossible for a user to navigate any higher in a particular site collection.

Comment: Thanks, James. That makes sense. This provided a recursive method to find the parent that I'm looking for: http://lawo.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/dispose-spweb-objects-while-iterating-to-parentweb/ I fetch the title inside the `if` (before the `using`).